# How to get child node by number from XML file

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, xmlnode

Am trying to make sorting of data in my XML by attribute "times" and show it in TreeView

I have XML file like

```
<main>
  <data url="http://www.r.com/" data="13.10.2013 20:16:33" times="6" />
  <data url="https://www.google.com/" data="13.10.2013 20:16:14" times="5" />
  <data url="http://ya.com/" data="13.10.2013 19:21:15" times="26" />
</main>
```

what i want is to sort all nodes by attribute "times". If i can get any of node (1, 2 or 3), that i can take attribute and compare it with first ono - so can make some sorting. but i can't get required element.

so the question - how can i get any nodes from XML file, if i know only it's serial number  or how can i sort XML file by some attribute?

Found, if i have id - i can use simething like

```
XmlDocument myXml = new XmlDocument();
myXml.Load(myfile);
myXml.GetElementById(`here put id`).GetAttribute("required attribute")
```

but i havent any id.

**EDIT:**

```
<main>
  <data url="http://ya.com/" data="13.10.2013 19:21:15" times="**26**" />
  <data url="http://www.r.com/" data="13.10.2013 20:16:33" times="**6**" />
  <data url="https://www.google.com/" data="13.10.2013 20:16:14" times="**5**" />
</main>
```

Comment: your question is not clear!what are you trying to get from that xml!

Comment: i'm try to sort each nodes by attribure - so result must be like in my edit - please see it

Comment: and how about this worlds in my post `Am trying to make sorting of data in my XML file and show it in TreeView`

Comment: so you want to sort that data by date and then show it in tree view!

Comment: not by date - by visited times, attribute "times"

Comment: How 26,5,6 ? Which order is this?

Comment: just change it - from bigger to smaller - typo in EDIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am new to Linq->Xml, So I have no idea about efficiency in this but it seems to work.

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var ordered = xdoc.Descendants("data")
                  .OrderByDescending(x => int.Parse(x.Attribute("times").Value))
                  .ToArray();
xdoc.Root.RemoveAll();
xdoc.Root.Add(ordered);
```

Comment: never use LINQ... just start to read about, but anyway, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to show data in TreeView,you need to first get all the data from xml and then sort it by `times`

```
XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(url);
//extract all data from xml
var data=doc.Descendants("data")
            .Select(x=>
               new
               {
                   url=x.Attribute("url").Value,
                   data=x.Attribute("data").Value,
                   times=int.Parse(x.Attribute("times").Value)
               } 
);

foreach(var datum in data.OrderByDescending(x=>x.times))
{
    datum.url;
    datum.data;
    datum.times;
}
```

Comment: Ordering needs to be descending it seems :)